# How to allow use of fopen and getimagesize on urls without schemes e.g. // instead of http://

Tags: nginx, php

I set open_basedir in the site conf.  but I noticed errors "open_basedir restriction in effect" when using getimagesize with uri that start with //  instead of http://

how to allow this?  Can adding // to open_basedir be a security risk?

Comment: How would `fopen` or `getimagesize` know which scheme to use?

Comment: I thought it could use the current scheme sent by the server if it exists.  which in this case should be when serving a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the scheme back to the URL yourself. Anything starting with `/` is read from the local filesystem, and if you added that to open_basedir, it would allow reading the entire filesystem, making it just about the same as turning it off.

Comment: is // interpreted as / by php?

Comment: No, it's interpreted as such by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

// is meant to be a 'relative' url that inherits the base page scheme. I don't think that makes sense in a PHP environment as there is no base page to reference.

Comment: Thanks, but when serving a page, the current scheme is already known to php through the web server e.g. nginx.  can't it inherit that scheme?